# Can we add more RAM sockets on a motherboard?

Tags: memory, motherboard, sockets

If a motherboard has only 4 RAM sockets, then can we add more up to 5 or 6 sockets?

Comment: I can actually imagine some people having this question... Though it's more useful if it said: 2 RAM sockets (like in a crippled Dell Vostro) and wanting to add 2 more.

Answer (score 13):

No. The memory control logic is a fundamental feature of the motherboard, not something extensible.

Comment: Some motherboards have blank areas with leads for another RAM slot.  I've always wondered if soldering in a new bank would work.

Answer (score 1):

If You use Linux and have GPU with lot off RAM: http://kerneltrap.org/node/143

You can also use i-RAM storage device and make swap on it: http://techreport.com/articles.x/9312/2.

I think both options are to expensive and complicated for normal use, but it's possible.

**//edit:**

One more interesting link (it can by consider as a little off topic but in my opinion somehow related): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Direct_Memory_Access

**//edit2:**

http://www.thefind.com/computers/info-memory-expansion-board, but Wikipedia classified them as "legacy" ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expansion_card )

Comment: Yup, I remember such things being offered for Macs (I think they were for 30 pin (ie 8 bit vs current 64) simms).

Modern memory is clocked too hard for that to work.